# how to add multipe ClassAdmin for one entity in symfony sonata bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have a Admin class name `VenteAdmin.php` with entity `Vente`:

```
class VentesAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        // ... 
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {

    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {

    }

    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {

    }
}
```

this is my `services.yml`:

```
services:
    admin.facture:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\VentesAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Ventes, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Ventes, label: Facture, icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-file-text\"></i>" }
```

and I want to add another admin class name `DevisAdmin.php` by the same entity `Ventes` but with other listFields, showFields, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to define a different servide ID, pointing to the new admin class with the same entity:

```
services:
    admin.devis:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\DevisAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Ventes, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Devis, label: Devis, icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-file-text\"></i>" }
```

Comment: is working but is a problem the DevisAdmin and VentesAdmin makes same ShowFields and ListFields how can i define ShowFields and List fields diferent between devisAdmin and VentesAdmin ??

Comment: I'm no sure to understand you question very well, but If you have different admin class then you have different ShowFields and ListFields methods.

Comment: I have different admin class in the same entity and when i want to generate a different ShowFields and ListFields methods to my different admin class i have the problem

Comment: What problem? please, update your question with you issue.